# How do you link questions you asked on a different computer after creating an open id?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I'm new to these sites and posted a question on a work computer. I got great results and when I got home made an open id and signed up. Is there any way to connect that question to this account or is it lost forever in the ether?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can find the question you can flag it for moderator attention and ask for the accounts to be merged.

There will probably be some e-mailing between the team and you to verify ownership, but that's normal.